# How to make HTML canvas for emscripten without borders

Tags: html, emscripten

I have a simple C++ SDL2 program and I'm using emscripten to run it in the browser. Emscripten generates two files (javascript and webassembly) and it renders everything into HTML canvas. I found this simple HTML canvas on the internet and it works just fine but for some reason, it has white borders on the left and on the top. How can I remove these borders?
Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()"></canvas>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var Module = {
                canvas: (function() { return document.getElementById('canvas'); })()
            };
        </script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6ysE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the browser-default margin on the body-element.
You can remove it by adding some CSS to the head-element.

Example:

```html
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That was it, Thank you!